# angular.json : configuration for multiple library projects

Tags: angular, angular-cli, eslint, typescript-eslint, angular-eslint

My Angular application is composed of one 'Application' project and 20+ 'library' project. These libraries are consumed inside my main application. Everything is working fine.

I am using `eslint` package as linter for all the libraries, but every time i need to add any new config, I have to add it for each project manually,

for example: in order to enable eslint `cache` i need to go to every single library project and duplicate the cache related config for each project.

looks like `angular.json` itself doesn't provides a way to create some common shareable config, we have to add everything for each project manually, there is nothing as global level configs applied to all the projects.

```
"lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-eslint/builder:lint",
          "options": {
            "eslintConfig": "./.gmslib-eslintrc.json",
            "lintFilePatterns": [
              "projects/libs/google-sheet/src/**/*.ts",
              "projects/libs/google-sheet/src/**/*.html"
            ]
          }
        }
```

repeating configs is bloating up my `angular.json` file although for most of the libraries i am using same set of configs with just few minor differences. Is there any way we could handle this to have one global level configs available to each projects.